# How to update yt module to last version via pip?

Tags: python-3.x, yt

How to update yt module via pip? I still have 3.5.1 after

```
pip install yt
```

How to obtain 3.6.1, please?

Comment: `pip install --upgrade yt`, iirc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
pip install [package_name] --upgrade
```

and in your case:
`pip install yt --upgrade`